# How do plugins store their configuration/field data?

Tags: plugins

I'm creating a custom Commerce License and I notice that I'm handling defaultConfiguration(), buildConfigurationForm(), submitConfigurationForm(), and buildFieldDefinitions(), but I cannot figure out where in the database this information is stored. I know that it must exist somewhere as the data loads up when I view the entity, but I cannot seem to find it. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with Configuration that would exist in a sync folder despite the similar names.

I'd assume buildFieldDefinitions() has something to do with it, but I cannot seem to figure out exactly what that method is doing at all.

Comment: All configuration is stored in the `config` table in the database.

Comment: Thought that'd be the case, but I don't see any entries whose names seem quite right. Do you know how the `name` col is set/determined in `config`?

Comment: Depends on what you are configuring.

Comment: All configuration is exported to the sync folder as well. So why does it matter where it is stored in the database?

Comment: Because what I'm describing is specifically not in the exported site config at all. See the packaged commerce license plugin: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_license/-/blob/8.x-2.x/src/Plugin/Commerce/LicenseType/Role.php. When a license is saved on a Product Variant, it's saved to `$this->configuration['license_role']`. Then when the edit form is loaded again, that value is used as the field default. But, exporting site config holds no reference to the value in `$this->configuration['license_role']`.

Comment: Normally configurable plugins are connected with a config entity to store the plugins configuration, but they don't need to. Plugins can be instantiated with configuration retrieved from any place, which for this plugin type is explained in the module code you have linked https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce_license/-/blob/8.x-2.x/src/Plugin/Commerce/LicenseType/LicenseTypeInterface.php.

Comment: Somehow missed that Interface you linked -- thanks for that. Looking through the db again I did find a `plugin_confguration` col in some associated tables. I didn't realize those were hex/seralized data. Converting the hex string revealed the data I had been expecting to find. Was hoping to set some of this data during a migration but it might be trickier than I'd anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the answer is "the data is probably the config table... but it could also be anywhere else depending on the implementation." In the commerce_license example I noted, instances of `LicenseTypes` on Product variants get their own entry in `commerce_product_variation__license_type`, where the data for that instance is stored in the `license_type_target_plugin_configration` column. Just like data stored in the `config` table, this is a hex blob which, when decoded, is the config field data as a serialized array.